# how come the ethereum I bought with my bitcoins aren't appearing?

Tags: wallets, ether

I am a complete newb,

I sent 6 ethereum worth of bitcoin to my etherbase wallet, I know they were sent correctly but they do not appear in my etherbase wallet. Where might they be? How do I get them to show up in my wallet? I had the bitcoins I tried to import them to my etheruem wallet in a popup window during the setup, within the program.

Comment: What do you mean "sent bitcoins for 6 ether"? Where did you send the bitcoins to? Do you mean you bought ether on an exchange using bitcoins, and then transferred the ether to your wallet?

Comment: perhaps that is easier to understand?

Answer (score 1):

Ethereum Wallet does not support Bitcoin or Bitcoin wallets. Therefore there is no way to actually send and/or store Bitcoin to your Ethereum Wallet.

What you can do is send Bitcoin through a service like Shapeshift which will receive the Bitcoin and send the equivalent amount of ETH to the address you provided. Then you will have ETH, not BTC.

It is impossible to answer your question without knowing what service you used to turn your BTC into ETH. If it is ShapeShift, you need to contact their support. If it is another exchange, such as Kraken or Poloniex, you need to contact their support.

If you are indeed synced and the balance of your address also shows 0 on etherscan.io, then the service you used to turn BTC into ETH probably had a hiccup or something went wrong or something got delayed. Reach out to them and determine what happened.

If you want quick and easy help then *be helpful*! Provide all information up front. The random support person is not magic and does not know what you did unless you tell them! Provide exactly what you did, where you did it, how you did it, when you did it, the address you sent BTC from, the amount of BTC you sent, and the ETH address you provided.

Comment: sorry I am new to this, i did it through shapeshift, i couldn't remember the name. Thanks a lot you have been very helpful and patient with me not knowing the jargon and terminology to explain things properly. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

An ether walet is actually a smart contract. You probably sent it to your ether account. But I suspect you just haven't synced geth with the blockchain. The first synch can take hours if done through the command line from scratch using the fast synch option and days if you tried doing through the gui. Search for mist first blockchain synch and you will have the answer to correcting you acount synchronization problems which make it appear that the ether is not their. Please mark this as answered if this helped you.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: Well I suppose it's not since I jump to conclusions regarding the geth synch as the issue but my intent was to elaborate more if she had additional questions about my attempt at answering. Thanks tho, just signed up and I'm trying to contribute because I see ethereums future potential being far more than it is now and growing unto something that helps to ensure mankind's survival and ability to thrive. I know you understand these words brother.

Comment: Welcome to the community! :)  When you're able to post a comment, it's usually better than jumping to a conclusion.  Then, if the asker confirms your guess, you can post the answer.  We try to have precise answers for precise questions (instead of vague questions with speculative answers).

Comment: you may be right about the syncing thing, my wallet is up and onscreen but there is a bar that's loading on top of the screen and it is taking forever...Thanks for all the help people!